# How do I replace columns with fewer than x values with NA in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix where most columns have 10 rows.  I want to replace all the values in each column that has fewer than 10 rows.  How do I accomplish this in R?

Thanks

Comment: A data.frame or matrix have fixed dimensions i.e. if a matrix is 4x5, it means there are 4 rows and 5 columns and all the columns have 4 elements in that matrix.  It is not clear what you meant

Comment: Sorry, I misstated things. All the columns have 10 rows, just some of the cells are empty.  So for any column where any cell is empty I want to replace all cells in that column with NA.

Comment: that you can do it with `df[,colSums(df=='')>0] <- NA` (assuming that the columns are `character` class

Comment: Won't that replace just the blank cells or will it replace all the cells in any column that has blanks?  The latter is desired.

Comment: it will replace all the cells in the column that has blanks ( i updated my comment)

Comment: What about if the columns are numeric?

Comment: You would do well to clean up your question rather than add details in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this

```
df[df==""] <- NA

 NAME DIST
1    A    0
2    A <NA>
3    A  100
4    A    2
5    A    1
6    A    4
7    A <NA>
8    A    1
9    A    1
```

#data

```
df <- data.frame(NAME = rep("A",9), DIST = c(0,"",100,2,1,4,"",1,1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it shortly.